# How to pass variable to children in .net maui?

Tags: .net, xaml, maui

im trying to create some kind of reusable message component that displays info/warning/err/ok message.

So in my content page its like

<views:MessageView />

but i need to pass props to this view from parent

like text of the message & type so developer can choose which one wants to display

also i would like to use MVVM but if that's problem i can use codebehind

i imagine something like this ?

<views:MessageView MessageText={Binding ErrMsg} MessageType={Binding Type} />

is it possible in .net maui ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No problem. First of all. Don't use `BindingContext` in your control. The control is dependent of the view it is currently attached to.

To communicate with your control you can read about [bindable-properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/bindable-properties)

So in your control it can look like this.

```cs
public static readonly BindableProperty MessageTextProperty =
    BindableProperty.Create(nameof(MessageText), typeof(string), typeof(MyControl));

public string MessageText
{
    get => (string)GetValue(MessageTextProperty);
    set => SetValue(MessageTextProperty, value);
}
```

So when you bind to your ViewModel, it will fetch data and send it to your control.

**Update**

Here is complete code that is a common way to update a label.

```cs
public partial class MessageView : ContentView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty MessageTextProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(MessageText), typeof(string), typeof(MessageView), defaultValue: default(string), propertyChanged: OnTextChanged);

    private static void OnTextChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var messageView = (MessageView)bindable;
        messageView.MyLabel.Text = (string)newValue;
    }

    public string MessageText
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(MessageTextProperty);
        set => SetValue(MessageTextProperty, value);
    }

    public MessageView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

In your view you use the control like this:

```xml
<controls:MessageView MessageText="{Binding MyMessage}" />
```

With the Binding in the ViewModel

```cs
[ObservableProperty]
private string myMessage = "Hello everybody!";
```

Comment: Can you please provide dummy example for whole thing ?

Comment: Also is it possible to do it with MVVM approach ? @Peter Wessberg

Comment: Well, this is MVVM, ContentView is just content in your View with its own logic. It is great for reusable code. If you don't need that you can just do it with Labels, Entry and whatnot. MVVM is a separation of code, where Views have controls, and ViewModel take care of logic. There are many similar patterns you can use or add on this. If you want a good way of coding, read up on SOLID, Clean Code and Domain Driven Design (DDD). Read more about MVVM on [Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/maui/mvvm)

Comment: So how would you implement same thing using MessageViewModel and bind it as BindingContext for MessageView ?

Answer (score 0):

> i imagine something like this ?
>
> <views:MessageView MessageText={Binding ErrMsg} MessageType={Binding Type} />
>
> is it possible in .net maui ?

Yes, and more specifically you can use [ContentView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/contentview?view=net-maui-7.0) to achieve it.

You can refer to the answer I post before: [Binding Custom ListView Control](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75587366/19902734).