# BindablePropertys setter not called only when it is used in xaml

Tags: xaml, xamarin, maui

I'm trying to create a content view and I would like to encapsulate in it as much logic as possible to keep my code DRY but I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or is just a limitation on how bindable properties and thier accessors trigger the notification change event. Anyway here is my example

ContentView.xaml.cs

```cs
public static readonly BindableProperty TotalItemsProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(TotalItems), typeof(int), typeof(SortingPageView),
    defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay);

public int TotalItems
{
    get => (int)GetValue(TotalItemsProperty);
    set
    {
        SetValue(TotalItemsProperty, value);
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CurrentPageText));
    }
}

public string CurrentPageText { get => $" / {TotalPages}"; }
```

ContentView.xaml

```xml
<Grid ColumnDefinitions="50, auto, 50" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="End">
    <Image Grid.Column="0" IsVisible="{Binding CanGoBack}" Source="left_arrow.png" HeightRequest="30">
        <Image.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="GoBack"/>
        </Image.GestureRecognizers>
    </Image>
    <HorizontalStackLayout Margin="10, 0" Grid.Column="1">
        <Entry FontSize="20" Text="{Binding CurrentPage}"/>
        <Label FontSize="20" Text="{Binding CurrentPageText}" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
    </HorizontalStackLayout>
    <Image Grid.Column="2" Source="right_arrow.png" HeightRequest="30">
        <Image.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="GoNext"/>
        </Image.GestureRecognizers>
    </Image>
</Grid>
```

ViewModel.cs

```cs
public  async Task LoadJobs(bool resetCurrentPage = false)
{
    this.IsLoading = true;

    try
    {
        if(resetCurrentPage)
        {
            this.CurrentPage = 1;
        }

        var jobs = await this.jobsService.GetJobs(Filter, Pagination);

        this.InitialJobs = jobs.Items.Select(x => new JobDto(x)).ToList();
        this.TotalItems = jobs.TotalItems;   -- only this line is importent

        MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            this.Jobs.Clear();
            this.Jobs.AddRange(jobs.Items);
        });
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {

    }
    finally 
    { 
        this.IsLoading = false;
    }
}
```

Please note that the TotalItems property is not displayed in the actual ContentView.xaml
Is only used to calculate other properties based of it but it's setter is never called (had a breakpoint on it) only when the TotalItems property has in the xaml, so am I doing something wrong here?

PS
ContentView.xaml.cs Constructor

```
    public SortingPageView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Content.BindingContext = this;
    }
```

**UPDATE**

The view model is not for the contentView, it so for the view in witch I want to display the content view.

And from what I understand I need to define a BindableProperty with a accessero property in the content view and in the view model I have that totalItems property that I want to pass down. Kinda like in vue, angular

Comment: is `TotalItems` defined in the VM or the code behind?  Your code shows it defined in the code-behind, but you are also referencing it in the VM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I think that the problem was either in the way I did my bindings in view model or that I didn't add in the conentView.xaml the

```
BindingContext="{x:Reference this}"
```

on the root element in the contentView in my case grid

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Name="this"
             x:Class="MedMark.Components.PagingFunctionality">

    <Grid BindingContext="{x:Reference this}" ColumnDefinitions="50, auto, 50" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="End">
```

you can see that this is the actual content view and contrary to what I read that you should bind to the binding context of the content view I still did it and it works as expected
ContentView.xaml.cs

```
public partial class PagingFunctionality : ContentView
{
    public PagingFunctionality()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Content.BindingContext = this;
    }
}
```

Ok now I'll just paste some code to work as kinda of a template for others (or my future self :D)

ContentView.xaml.cs

```
public partial class PagingFunctionality : ContentView
{
    public PagingFunctionality()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Content.BindingContext = this;
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty TotalPagesProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(TotalPages), typeof(int), typeof(PagingFunctionality), 0,
        BindingMode.OneWay, propertyChanged: TotalPagesChanged);

    public static readonly BindableProperty CurrentPageProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(CurrentPage), typeof(int), typeof(PagingFunctionality), 0,
        BindingMode.TwoWay, propertyChanged: CurrentPageChanged);


    private static void TotalPagesChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var view = bindable as PagingFunctionality;
        view.NotifyPagingDetails();
    }

    private static void CurrentPageChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var view = bindable as PagingFunctionality;
        view.NotifyPagingDetails();
    }


    public int TotalPages 
    { 
        get => (int)GetValue(TotalPagesProperty);
        set => SetValue(TotalPagesProperty, value);
    }

    public int CurrentPage
    {
        get => (int)GetValue(CurrentPageProperty);
        set => SetValue(CurrentPageProperty, value);
    }

    public bool CanGoBack { get => this.CurrentPage > 1; }
    
    public bool CanGoNext { get => this.CurrentPage < this.TotalPages; }

    private void NotifyPagingDetails()
    {
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CanGoNext));
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CanGoBack));
    }

    private void GoBack(object sender, TappedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (CanGoBack)
        {
            this.CurrentPage--;
        }
    }

    private void GoNext(object sender, TappedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (CanGoNext)
        {
            this.CurrentPage++;
        }
    }
}
```

ContentView.xaml

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Name="this"
             x:Class="MedMark.Components.PagingFunctionality">

    <Grid BindingContext="{x:Reference this}" ColumnDefinitions="50, auto, 50" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="End">
        <Image 
            Grid.Column="0"
            IsVisible="{Binding CanGoBack}" 
            Source="left_arrow.png" HeightRequest="30">
            <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="GoBack"/>
            </Image.GestureRecognizers>
        </Image>
        <HorizontalStackLayout Margin="10, 0" Grid.Column="1">
            <Entry x:Name="CurrentPageLabel" Text="{Binding CurrentPage}" FontSize="20"/>
            <Label x:Name="TotalPageLabel" Text="{Binding TotalPages, StringFormat=' / {0}'}" FontSize="20" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
        </HorizontalStackLayout>
        <Image 
            Grid.Column="2" 
            IsVisible="{Binding CanGoNext}"
            Source="right_arrow.png" HeightRequest="30">
            <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="GoNext"/>
            </Image.GestureRecognizers>
        </Image>
    </Grid>
</ContentView>
```

JobsView.xaml

```
            <components:PagingFunctionality
                Grid.Column="1"
                TotalPages="{Binding TotalPages}"
                CurrentPage="{Binding CurrentPage}"/>
```

JobsViewModel.cs

```
    [ObservableProperty]
    [NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(TotalPages))]
    private int totalItems;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private int currentPage = 1;

    public int TotalPages { get => this.TotalItems % this.Pagination.PageSize == 0 ? this.TotalItems / this.Pagination.PageSize : this.TotalItems / this.Pagination.PageSize + 1; }

    partial void OnCurrentPageChanged(int oldValue, int newValue)
    {
        this.Pagination.CurrentPageNo = newValue;

        Task.Run(async () => await LoadJobs(false));
    }
```

As CurrentPageProperty in ContentView.xaml.cs has a BindingMode = TwoWay, here in the viewModel, I listen for changes in CurrentPage to load the according items.

Note that the logic for going to the next page is validated and triggered in the ContentView by the properties **CanGoNext** and **CanGoBack** and methods (that are bound to the tap event) **GoNext** and  **GoBack**

Answer (score 0):

When you create ContentViews, think of it like content in a ContentPage. So it should rely on that ContentPage's ViewModel and not have its own ViewModel or bind to itself. I would argue that if your ContentView need its own viewmodel you have made a design error somewhere. But that is a matter of opinion.

So remove your BindingContext that point to this, and move all the logic that is needed for the Control and relay on data and properties from the ViewModel from the View that the control is part of. You have not given us a complete code structure so I cannot show you how I think it should be. If you want to use bindnig and point to your own code you use Reference like `{Binding MessageText, Source={x:Reference ThisView}}` where ThisView is the `x:Name` of the Control you have.

Comment: If the contentView should not bind to itself then it will use the properties of it's view's view model right? If that is the case what are the point of those BindableProperties defined in contentView?

Comment: Those are so that the View can send data to the ContentView, often through the ViewModel. So it is the communication to the control and back. The different control inside the ContentView is assigned and controlled separately by the ContentView logic. Normally it goes View->ViewModel->ContentView when it comes to data and logic for MVVM. If you don't need data outside the ConentView you don't need BindableProperty. Then you just handle the different controls as a normal View. Does that make sense to you? :)

Comment: An example would be much appreciated, a blog post or a code snippet that presents how to handle data communication between vm and content view. For me I would like to pass as little data as possible to contentView and let it do all the calculation and notify changes for affected properties

Comment: I provided this answer some days ago. It show a ContentView interacting with a View and ViewModel: [How to pass variable to children in .net maui?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76943224/10528003)

Comment: And in that example, if I want to display in my content view MessageTextUpper and MessageTextCamelCase how would I do it without passing them independently from the view model becasue that kinda defeats half of the power of a component

Comment: Then you have another Property eg TextMode that is set and tell how the text is displayed in the MessageTextProperty. When you change the TextMode in your ViewModel, your ContentView modifies the MessageText Entry or Label  accordingly. The binding in the ContentView and in the ViewModel makes it all dynamic. I hope I understood your question correctly. Another thing. In your example you have a binding from the Label to CurrentPageText. The only thing you need to do was to do MyLabel.Text = CurrentPageText, and when TotalItems changes you update that Label from a OnPropertyChange event.